# Python how to read binary file by chunks and specify the beginning offset

Tags: python

I have the code:

```
def read_chunks(infile, chunk_size):
    while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunk_size)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        else:
            return
```

This works when I need to read the file by chunks; however, sometimes I need to read the file two bytes at a time, but start reading at the next offset, not the next chunk. For example: 00 01 02 03 04, I would need to read "00 01", "01 02", "02 03", "03 04" for a chunk size of 2. The function currently reads it as "00 01", "02 03", "04". Is there a way to implement what I'm trying to do in the same function, or should this just be as a separate function? What would this look like? I still need the function to work as-is, so I'm wondering if there's a way to just implement what I'm trying to do, maybe as an argument. Not sure if it would be better to implement this in the current function or just do that in a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

Using **tell()** and **seek(n)** you can navigate the file pointer wherever you want in file.

> **tell()**: returns the current file position in a file stream
> **seek(n)**: sets the current file position to n in a file stream

```py
def read_chunks(infile, chunk_size, offset=0):
    if( chunk_size + offset < 1 ):
        return
    while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunk_size)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
            if offset != 0:
              if not infile.read(1): # eof reached
                return
              infile.seek(infile.tell()+offset-1)
              # -1 to revert read(1)
        else:
            return


f = open("x", "rb") # read binary

for i in read_chunks(f,2,-1):
  print(i,end=" ")
```

#### Update:

- Opening file is using "rb" from "read binary" instead of "r"
- EOF check changed

#### Addition -> offset parameter:

- 0 (default value): reads chunks one after another
- positive n: skips n chunks between reads
- negative n: n previously read bytes are included in start of next chunk

Comment: Thank you. This works, but I have a question. How do you choose which method to use? For example, if I want to get 00 01, 02 03, 04 instead of 00 01, 01 02, 02 03, 03 04? Also, when I run the script it works until it reaches the end and is stuck in a loop. I'm reading the input file as binary, also, not as a text file.

Comment: 1. Swiching modes can be possible via parameter and depedning on the value of the parameter the code can be modified accordingly.
2. I'm looking to make it work for binary files right now.

Comment: Alright, thank you. If you don't mind when you update it for binary files, can you update it to use a parameter for switching between modes easily?

Comment: Updated it for binaries. Going to add the parameter as well.

Comment: @4xZnskJp you must be good to go. I did my tests and it worked as expected, let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: One last thing, if you set the chunk_size to 1 and the offset to -1, it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Could you add something that identifies if these two values are set and prevent this from happening if you don't mind?

Comment: Maybe by printing an error or something.

Comment: The infinite loop is the right execution in that case, reads 1 byte goes back 1 so it reads again 1 and goes back one and so on, which is what you told it to do but i get what you mean. So if you want to add constrains on it you can make a condition in start of the function (before while) about the values chunk_size and offset as you wish.  
For example i would eliminate any negative offset with absolute value greater or equal to chunk size to avoid any loop like chunk_size = 1 and offset -1 but you can implement anything you want there.

Comment: Do you mind updating it to add that? Other than that, it should be good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244125/discussion-between-ioannis-kokkalis-and-4xznskjp).